# SwiftUI in Storyboard Project Comes Up Blank

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storyboard, uihostingcontroller

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWL7W8SLfeo

...on importing a SwiftUI file into an existing Storyboard project. When it didn't work in my existing project I made a brand new one from scratch (Xcode 13.2.1) and it doesn't seem to matter. When I click the link to go to the ViewController hosting the view... it still comes up blank.

**The Hosting ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class PokeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theContainer: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
        addChild(childView)
        theContainer.addSubview(childView.view)
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

**The SwiftUI:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Here's the AppDelegate and SceneDelegate if that helps:

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

**SceneDelegate**

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

The PokeViewController class is connected to the correct ViewController in the storyboard... and the SwiftUIView is connected to the  view. But when I visit PokeViewController... it's just blank (though I KNOW any code I have is being run. If I do something like an ImagePicker and set its default launch to "True"... it launches... and I can see the images... but once I'm done or click cancel it's back to the same blank page.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to pin the childView.view to the edges with programmatic constraints

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks. How do you know this? Is there some sort of Developer's page on this that I missed?

Comment: Experience, I don’t think it is written anywhere. It is a UIView with no frame by adding constraints that “pin” it the View to all the sides it will behave as it would behave in SwiftUI. I actually have a UIView extension that “pins” the view to an argument that is a parent.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why it worked, at all, for the guy in the YouTube video. Is it just because he was using a Navigation controller?

Comment: I haven’t looked at the video. Different UIKit Views behave differently, if you add it to a UIStackView you wouldn’t have to pin it either. If I remember correctly you don’t have to ping it either if you do something like self.view = childView.view but I am not sure that you can do this with a hosting controller. The documentation provides clues on the behavior of the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add after

```
theContainer.addSubview(childView.view)
```

following code:

```
childView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let constraints = [
    childView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainer.topAnchor),
    childView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainer.leftAnchor),
    theContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.view.bottomAnchor),
    theContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: childView.view.rightAnchor)
]

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

/// Notify the hosting controller that it has been moved to the current view controller.
childView.didMove(toParent: self)
```

There is an extension:

```
 extension UIViewController {

    /// Add a SwiftUI `View` as a child of the input `UIView`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - swiftUIView: The SwiftUI `View` to add as a child.
    ///   - view: The `UIView` instance to which the view should be added.
    func addSwiftUIbodyView<Content>(_ swiftUIView: Content, to view: UIView) where Content: View {
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)

        /// Add as a child of the current view controller.
        addChild(hostingController)

        /// Add the SwiftUI view to the view controller view hierarchy.
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)

        /// Setup the contraints to update the SwiftUI view boundaries.
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constraints = [
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingController.view.bottomAnchor),
            view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hostingController.view.rightAnchor)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

        /// Notify the hosting controller that it has been moved to the current view controller.
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you know this? Is there some sort of Developer's page on this that I missed?

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually I have found the extension somewhere on GitHub. I don't remember where.